# Noise problem in blocking converter

Tags: power, transformer, power-electronics

In a blocking converter, with the increase of the input voltage, the sound noise in the transformer increases greatly.
The converter is used to make two 12V isolated with a current of 0.2 amps.
The circuit design is:
[image]
1- What steps should be taken to design the transformer of this type of converter? Is the air gap necessary?
I know the design of the flyback converter transformer.
2- What could be the reason for transformer noise when the input voltage increases?

Comment: Hello and welcome! The best way to get good answers is to ask good questions.  It looks as though no component values or transformer parameters (at least, I'm *guessing* from context that's a transformer?) were entered on the diagram; you may want to improve it to attract more interested answers.